# Н или НН в "варе*ая"

Tags: причастия

Верно ли я понимаю, что
1) "Вареная картошка" пишется с одной Н
2) "Варенная на огне картошка" с НН?
И возникает это из-за появления зависимого слова, верно?

Comment: Ни разу не встречал слова "варенная".

Answer (score 4):

Да, отглагольное прилагательное "варёный" преображается в причастие при добавлении приставки или зависимых слов.

> В отглагольных прилагательных, **образованных от бесприставочных
>   глаголов несовершенного вида**, пишется одно н, например: правленый,
>   вяленый, жареный, варёный, мочёный, кипячёный, глаженый, кованый,
>   кошеный, стриженый, стираный, ломаный, мощёный, плетёный, гружёный,
>   плавленый, мороженый, а также раненый (хотя образовано от двувидового
>   глагола ранить). С одним н пишется прилагательное смышленый.
>
> Исключения: С двумя н пишутся отглагольные прилагательные,
>   образованные от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида:
>   виданный, виденный, деланный, желанный, слыханный, считанный,
>   нежданный-негаданный.
>
> Примечание 1. Вышеприведенные отглагольные прилагательные при наличии
>   зависимых слов переходят в разряд причастий и пишутся с двумя н,
>   например: мощенные булыжником улицы, груженные лесом вагоны, раненный в
>   ногу боец, стриженный парикмахером мальчик.
>
> Примечание 2. С двумя н пишутся отглагольные прилагательные,
>   образованные от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида с
>   суффиксами -ован (-ёван), например:балованный, рискованный,
>   корчёванный, линованный. В отглагольных прилагательных кованый,
>   жёваный сочетания ов (ев) входят в состав корня, а не суффикса.

**[ВА́РЕННЫЙ](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/753622)**, вареная, вареное; варен, варена, варено. прич. страд. прош. вр. от варить. **Пирожки, варенные на меду**.

---

P. S. Обратите внимание, что у прилагательного и у причастия - разные ударения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Картошка на огне все-таки варёная, если только вы не хотите сказать "варенная" (как у Галины Аванесовой) / сваренная.

Comment: "Пирожки, варенные на меду" - пример из словаря, ссылка кликабельна.